# C# How do you set richtextbox text to default?

Tags: c#, fonts, richtextbox, default

When some one puts a highlighted sentence to my richtextbox.
For example,

[image]

I want to make them type default text if they want to. Let's say if user clicks a button and want it to make default text. How do I do that?

I have tried

```
Font arialFont = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Regular);   
richTextBox1.SelectAll();
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = arialFont;
richTextBox1.BackColor = Color.White; // i also tried Color.Transparent but it only return error message "Control does not support transparent background colors"
// RichTextBox's property says that Appearance - BackColor - Window, but it didn't even exist on Color.~
```

How can I set text all in default state in RichTextBox?

I'm sorry for unclear question.

when a user copies a text that is hightlighted text like above picture. And if they keep type anything, the text is highlighted too. But I don't want that to happen.

So I want to make a button to clear all text and make them to type a default text(no highlight, bold, italic, etc...)

I hope I explained my problem well this time. Sorry for unclear question.

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you are facing or trying to solve.

Comment: What does it mean _When some one puts a highlighted sentence_? And _I want to make them type default text if they want to._?

Comment: I don't really know what it's called when a text's background has color. I think it's called "text highlighted color".
I meant highlighted sentence for copying a sentence that is hightlighted on the back of the text. 
And default text to be meant with no highlight, bold, italic, or whatsoever.

Comment: Still not clear.  I can only guess you want `richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.White;`

Comment: Thank you LarsTech, I solved 99% of the problem by doing richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent; Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you LarsTech, sorry for my poor English. But I kind of solved the problem by doing richTextBox1.SelectionBackColor = Color.Transparent;

I didn't know about Selection has a lot of different function. Probably from next time, I need to look for more functions that's already in it.

Thank you for the hint and have a nice day!